# Script fails in upsert, with logstash output elasticsearch plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

**Environment**

DB: Sybase
Logstash: 2.2.0 with JDBC Plugin, Elasticsearch Output plugin

**SQL Query:**

```
select res.id as 'res.id', res.name as 'res.name', tag.name as 'tag.name'
from Res res, ResTags rt, Tags tag
where res.id *= rt.resrow and rt.tagid *= tag.id
```

**SQL Result:**

```
res.id | res.name | tag.name
0 | result0 | null
0 | result0 | tagA
1 | result1 | tagA
1 | result1 | tagB
2 | result2 | tagA
2 | result2 | tagC
```

**Index Mapping:**

```
{ 
 "mappings": { 
  "res": { 
   "properties": { 
    "id": { "type": "long"},
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "tags": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": { "tagname": { "type": "string" }}
    }
   }
 }
}
```

**Conf File:**

```
input {
 jdbc {
  jdbc_driver_library => "jtds-1.3.1.jar"
  jdbc_driver_class => "Java::net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
  jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:jtds:sybase://hostname.com:1234/schema"
  jdbc_user => "george"
  jdbc_password => "monkey"
  jdbc_fetch_size => 100
  statement_filepath => "/home/george/sql"
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
  action => "update"
  index => "myres"
  document_type => "res"
  document_id => "%{res.id}"
  script_lang => "groovy"
  hosts => [ "my.other.host.com:5921" ]
  upsert => ' {
    "id" : %{res.id},
    "name" : "%{res.name}",
    "tags" :[{ "tagname": "%{tag.name}" }]
  }'
  script => '
    if (ctx._source.res.tags.containsValue(null)) {
      // if null has been added replace it with actual value
      cts._source.res.tags = [{"tagname": "%{tag.name}" }];
    else {
      // if you find the tag, then do nothing
      if (ctx._source.res.tags.containsValue("%{tag.name}")) {}
      else {
        // if the value you try to add is not null
        if (%{tag.name} != null)
           // add it as a new object into the tag array
           ctx._source.res.tags += {"tagname": "%{tag.name}"};
        }
     }
   '
 }
}
```

The GOAL is to add the multiple rows returned from the database into ES, concatenating the tags as new objects (this is simplified example, so add_tag and filters do not do the job, as I have json structure deeper than 2 levels (nested of nested, etc))

The desired outcome after the bulk upload into ES would be:

```
{
 "hits": {
   "total": 3,
   "max_score": 1,
   "hits": [ {
     "_index": "myres",
     "_type": "res",
     "_id": 0,
     "_score": 1,
     "_source": {
       "res": {
         "id":0,
         "name": "result0",
         "tags": [{"tagname": "tagA"}],
         "@version": "2",
         "@timestamp": "2016-xx-yy..."
       }
      },{
     "_index": "myres",
     "_type": "res",
     "_id": 1,
     "_score": 1,
     "_source": {
       "res": {
         "id":1,
         "name": "result1",
         "tags": [{"tagname": "tagA"},{"tagname": "tagB"}],
         "@version": "2",
         "@timestamp": "2016-xx-yy..."
       }
      }{
     "_index": "myres",
     "_type": "res",
     "_id": 2,
     "_score": 1,
     "_source": {
       "res": {
         "id":2,
         "name": "result2",
         "tags": [{"tagname": "tagA"},{"tagname": "tagC"],
         "@version": "2",
         "@timestamp": "2016-xx-yy..."
       }
      }
     }
...
```

**ISSUE:** if in the conf, output section the script is not commented out, the below error pops out. If the script is not included, then only the initial tags (as expected) are imported, and the second ones are not.

It looks like script is not working within elasticsearch output.

**ERROR message:**

```
    [400] {"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 
1: script or doc is missing;
2: script or doc is missing;
3: script or doc is missing;],"status":400]} {:class=> ... bla bla ...}
```

**NOTES**

- To avoid wasting peoples' time, doc_as_upsert => true also does not work as expected. It just keeps on updating / overwriting and just keeps the latest row of the db.
- Also, the river plugin for jdbc to ES does not support nested of nested structure so that does not work eithe

Comment: Have you tried enabling the `scripted_upsert` flag? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-scripted_upsert

Comment: Yes. It still fails.

Comment: It looks like upsert and script are mutual exclusive. Also, when you have scripted upsert you need to keep the upsert: {} even though it is empty (at least that is my impression from the documentation0

Comment: Actually, `upsert` works with and without `script` according [to the source](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb). In case of `script`, `upsert` is used only if `scripted_upsert` is false. You should try storing your script in a file and use the `script_type: file` instead.

Comment: I disagree. It does not work with script, even if the script is empty. Please provide a solid example of the above scenario as an answer if you believe so.

Comment: Also check online, there is a similar issue with doc_as_upsert and script (mutually exclusive).

Comment: `script` does work in concert with `upsert`as can be seen in the official documentation of the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts). Time permitting, I will provide an example, but the above links already shows that it is supported.

Comment: Update and Bulk Update are different. If script is not the issue, then what would be wrong with the above question?

Comment: "Bulk update" can include many "updates", but the semantics of those parameters remains the same. You can read that in the [bulk update doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update) which sends you back to the Update API doc. Still need to wrap my head around it, but there's a simple explanation  somewhere.

Comment: Would you like to chat? I cannot invite you as I am new

Comment: Chat room is here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105281/es-scripted-update

Comment: I cannot talk (no 20 points). Lets leave it.

Comment: Earn some points and get back in there :)

Comment: Not possible now. Catch up later

Comment: As soon as I get a few minutes, I'll post an answer, unless someone else does in the meantime.

Comment: @E.P. - Did you find a solution for this? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: I have written an article with examples that show how to execute scripted upserts - see: https://alexmarquardt.com/2019/12/17/exploring-the-capabilities-of-logstash-and-elasticsearch-scripted-upserts/

Comment: @E.P. - Did you find a solution for this? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: Apologies I do not remember. This was years ago.